# Подключение css в Yii, пути и assetBase

Tags: yii, css

Подключаю css файл следующим способом:

```
$pathToCss = CHtml::asset(Yii::getPathOfAlias('css'));
$clientScript->registerCssFile($pathToCss . '/nyroModal.css');
```

Внутри этого файла есть ссылки на картинки следующего вида:

```
background: #FFF url(../img/ajax-loader-large.gif) no-repeat;
```

В итоге получается картинки пытаются подгрузиться по адресу:

> assets/img/ajax-loader-large.gif

адрес у css:

> assets/namePath/nyroModal.css

Как можно разрулить ситуацию, чтобы ссылалась на нужную папку, не изменяя css файл и не перекладывая в другие папки?

Comment: а где они лежат-то по-настоящему?

Comment: @Etki по настоящему, есть некая папка, в которой лежат папки css / js / img . Получается по адресу /assets/kkeo32/css он берет из папки css, и т.д. В старой версии так и получалось, по адресу "../img/ajax-loader-large.gif" - выходил из папки css, и нормально доходил в img.

На данный момент решил не использовать nyroModal, другое модальное окно взял )